# How can I determine which component is creating a new user?

Tags: development, plugin

I'm working on a tricky User plugin that needs to do certain things only if being called from a 3rd party component. I could check the option in the url, but I need to consider that the user may be added by way of a 3rd party using MVC and and the model directly, not necessarily with a link FOR that 3rd party component.

Is there a way to determine this?

**Update:**
Ancient problem, but was still haunting me, so if of any interest to anyone, I created a Logging class that can track where updates of this nature are done, and save the data and parameters involved for later review.  Its freely available at [JSE Github](https://github.com/Joomla-StackExchange/glogger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `Itemid` in the url. If there is no `Itemid`, you should create at least a hidden menu item for the 3rd party registration page. The `Itemid` of the menu can be obtained manually (admin area -> menu):

[image]

or by some codes inside your plugin:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$item_id = $app->input->get('Itemid');

$menu = $app->getMenu();
$items = $menu->getItems('component', 'com_3rd_party');

foreach ($items as $item)
{
    if ($item->id == $item_id)
    {
        echo 'This is 3rd party!';
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes that an AJAX call uses an itemid - sorry, no dice.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could try using the `onUserAfterSave` ([Documentation Ref](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onUserAfterSave)) plugin event that will get triggered when a user record is update or when a new user is added. With this plugin event comes the `$isnew` boolean argument. `true` is when a new record is added.

Hope this helps

Comment: That's actually the event i'm working with - i want to differentiate between additions from the admin backend, a 3rd party social component, and our component.